# enthalpy–entropy chart in PHP

Tags: php, math

Does anyone know a library which generates [enthalpy–entropy charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy%E2%80%93entropy_chart) (h-s chart, Mollier h,x Diagramm in german)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's always the `gnuplot` extension for PHP. I've never plotted an enthalpy-entropy chart with `gnuplot`, but I'm sure it's perfectly capable.

http://php-gnuplot.sourceforge.net/

---

Perhaps a better option is to not use the extension, and run `gnuplot` directly from a shell script instead. This way you have access to every feature of `gnuplot`, and aren't constrained by what the extension does/doesn't provide.

Here's a pretty good guide on running `gnuplot` from a shell script:

[http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/intro/working-e.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20101113155819/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/intro/working-e.html)

And if you need a little primer on `gnuplot`, there is:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gnuplot/

Once you have the script, it can be called via [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in PHP. Don't forget to `chmod +x gnuplot-script.sh` first to make it executable.

```
exec('/path/to/gnuplot-script.sh');
```